# Power Query Two Excel Files with No Header Row in Each Files

Tags: excel, database, powerquery

i've been trying to combine 2 excel files with same template (no header row). Unique identifier is in the first column.
I'm trying to use power query but show no progress.
Here's the data
[data1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsRmm.png)
[data2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqKfE.png)

I expect output such as
[output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p879F.png)
[output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/365Xz.png)

I've been trying with power query and it results duplicate values with null data in other columns
[Power Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22vat.png)

Any idea how to merge it? I'm trying to merge other files but i'm using simple one to use the fundamental.

Please kindly advise.

Thanks

Comment: This appears to be spamseed. Flagging as spam.

Comment: Thats not spam - it's homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Import the data1, first transpose the table, then promote the headers
2. Import data2 with promoting the headers
3. Append data1 and data2 as new

Appending

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: Hi peter, thank you for your insight. It seems the same treatment as using tableau. 
I'm going to merge financial statements from a lot of files. It will be easier to analyst data. IT works. But it will be hard if i have to promote header from every query. The case is if the files is over 100 files.

Comment: You only need to define the procedure once and then you can bulk import all files in a folder like shown here: https://sqlitybi.com/loading-multiple-excel-files-from-a-folder-in-power-bi/. The files that need the transposition (data1) have to be in a separate folder though.

Comment: i still don't get it. i've been following the steps on those link. but it will result differently

Comment: sorry and right now i've done accepting